# Extending ApplicationUser Not Propagating to Table Schema

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have extended my ApplicationUser class with FirstName, LastName but when I create a migration and database the new properties do not show up.  Any thoughts?

My `ApplicationUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
{
    //extend with additional properties here
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

My `AppDbContext`:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public AppDbContext()
        : base(ConfigurationSetting.DatabaseConnectionName)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ConfigurationSetting> ConfigurationSettings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Place> Places { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CloudFiles.CloudFile> CloudFiles { get; set; }

    public static AppDbContext Create()
    {
        return new AppDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
    }

    public bool InitializeDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is what is created when I create a migration (only providing part of the migration code):

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Users",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                    EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = c.String(),
                    SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                    LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");
```

Comment: have you tried the [NotMapped] attribute on those properties ? its not going to map them to the database

Comment: @alexo But I want those properties to appear in the database to store values.

Comment: aaa, they do not show up, i thought u need them that way. well you declared variables, not properties. try making them properties and it should work

Comment: OMG. I totally missed that.  I forgot to add the accessors!  Thanks @alexo.  If you create an answer out of your comment, I will mark it as THE answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the variables as properties:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
{
    //extend with additional properties here
    public string FirstName { get; set ;}
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```